# Start and Stop Printing with 2 keywords in AWK

Tags: linux, awk

I have this ...

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{if($1 == "#BEGIN") while($1 != "#END") print}
```

what I want the output to print is this when the input file is read in.

```
This is a simple test file.
#BEGIN
These lines should be extracted by our script.

Everything here will be copied.
#END
That should be all.
#BEGIN
Nothing from here.
#END
user$ extract.awk test1.txt
These lines should be extracted by our script.

Everything here will be copied.
user$
```

Only the first set of BEGIN and END text will be copied. Not sure on how the best way to do this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using awk

Try:

```
$ awk 'f && /^#END/{exit} f{print} /^#BEGIN/{f=1}' test1.txt
These lines should be extracted by our script.

Everything here will be copied.
```

How it works:

- `f && /^#END/{exit}`

  If `f` is nonzero and this line starts with `#END`, exit.
- `f{print}`

  If variable `f` is nonzero, print this line.
- `/^#BEGIN/{f=1}`

  If this line starts with `#BEGIN`, set variable `f` to one.

## Using sed

```
$ sed -n '/^#BEGIN/{n; :a; /^#END/q; p; n; ba}' test1.txt 
These lines should be extracted by our script.

Everything here will be copied.
```

How it works:

- `/^#BEGIN/{...}`

  When we reach a line starting with `#BEGIN`, execute the commands in curly braces.  These commands are:
- `n`

  Read in the next line.
- `:a`

  Define label `a`.
- `/^#END/q`

  If the current line starts with `#END`, then quit.
- `p`

  Print this line.
- `n`

  Read in the next line.
- `ba`

  Branch (jump) back to label `a`.

## Making the awk command into a script

#### Method 1

Create this script file:

```
$ cat script1
#!/bin/sh
awk 'f && /^#END/{exit} f{print} /^#BEGIN/{f=1}' "$1"
```

This can be executed as:

```
$ bash script1 test1.txt 
These lines should be extracted by our script.

Everything here will be copied.
```

#### Method 2

Create this file:

```
$ cat script.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
f && /^#END/{exit}
f{print}
/^#BEGIN/{f=1}
```

Run it as follows:

```
$ awk -f script.awk test1.txt 
These lines should be extracted by our script.

Everything here will be copied.
```

Or, make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x script.awk
```

And execute it:

```
$ ./script.awk test1.txt
These lines should be extracted by our script.

Everything here will be copied.
```

## Making the awk script into a shell function

```
$ extract() { awk 'f && /^#END/{exit} f{print} /^#BEGIN/{f=1}' "$1"; }
$ extract test1.txt 
These lines should be extracted by our script.

Everything here will be copied.
```

## Making the sed command into a script

Create this file:

```
$ cat script.sed
#!/bin/sed -nf
/^#BEGIN/{n; :a; /^#END/q; p; n; ba}
```

Make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x script.sed
```

And, run it:

```
$ ./script.sed test1.txt
These lines should be extracted by our script.

Everything here will be copied.
```

Comment: how would i put this as an awk file that i could call from the command line and then have the argument as the test1.txt

Comment: @JonathanMcCann I just added a script that you can call from the command line.  Also, if you are using this interactively, some people prefer shell functions to scripts and I included an example of that.

Comment: would u be willing to help with converting the sed into a sed script @John1024

Comment: ah I didn't have the -nf in the first line that's why it wasn't working! thanks @John1024 for all the help!